# How to make a library of extension methods do double duty - SL4 and .NET4

Tags: silverlight, poco

I have some utilities and extension methods that I would like to leverage in an SL4 app.  I know that to reference an assembly the project type has to be SL4 class library.  I also understand that SL is a subset of the .NET framework.  Therefore not all functionality is portable.  So assume all the code I want to leverage in my SL4 app is portable to SL4.

What is the easiest way to expose an existing project/plain-old-CLR-library to SL4?  I am looking for a maintainable workflow.  As I develop against the library I want to leverage the new features in my SL4 app without having to rewrite the code in an SL4 class library.

Surley there is an easy way that I am completely missing...

Comment: Sounds like you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465460/sharing-c-code-between-windows-and-silverlight-class-libraries

Comment: @Marc, That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  Repost as answer and I will choose it and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want [Sharing C# code between Windows and Silverlight class libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465460/sharing-c-code-between-windows-and-silverlight-class-libraries)

Another way you can do it is to just share(link) classes between your .NET library and your Silverlight library. An easy way to do this is to use the [ProjectLinker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921108%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) tool.