# Can't find namespace in Global

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, namespaces, wcf-ria-services

I have the job of getting a legacy project working again. This project was done many years ago using *Silverlight* and *C# Class Library's*.

The error I am getting is to do with a namespace inside the project file called *Silverlight.Business*:

**Code**

```
using Tcx = global::MapTools.Xml;
```

**Error:**

```
The type or namespace name "MapTools" could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

*MapTools* is a *C# Class Library* and *Silverlight.Business* is a *Silverlight Library*. Due to this I can't add a reference to *MapTools* inside the Silverlight project file.

The silverlight project does have a WCF RIA Service's Link but that does not connect to anything.

I am now wondering how the person that wrote the code has managed to call that namespace? I have tried researching how to add the MapTools.dll to the Global namespace but have not found anything.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As per my knowledge it is not possible to add reference of regular .net library to the silverlight project. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/465861/1505865) answer

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I don't want to create a Shared version as if the person who created this got it working I want to use the same way so I don't brake the code.

Answer (score 0):

To do that there should be an some tool been used .
We had used in our projects a Portable library which allowed us to communicate through cross type of projects , below is the link :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg597391(v=vs.100).aspx